# Display random image with link on website

Tags: javascript, php, image, random, hyperlink

I have a website where people can download pdf-documents. In order to make the site more appealing, I would now like to display a screenshot of the first page of a random report and if the user clicks on it, open the appropriate pdf-file from which the screenshot was taken.

Right now, I am using the following javascript code to achieve this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total_images = 3;
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
var random_img = new Array();
random_img[0] = '<a href="documents/report1.pdf"><img src="images/report1.jpg"><\/a>';
random_img[1] = '<a href="documents/report2.pdf"><img src="images/report2.jpg"><\/a>';
random_img[2] = '<a href="documents/report3.pdf"><img src="images/report3.jpg"><\/a>';
document.write(random_img[random_number]);
--></script>
```

This is working without any problems. However, there are new pdf-docs added all the time and editing the code everytime is kind of a pain. I've read that it might be possible to populate the javascript array using php. Unfortunately, I am a complete noob when it comes to that and am not sure how I would go about doing this and still have the screenshot link to to the right report.

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly inject php into javascript. What I mean is, php will be executed first on the server, serve the modified javascript to the client who will have no idea that there was ever php in the first place.

Assuming you have a php array of reports and the naming convention is similar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total_images = 3;
    var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
    var random_img = [
                      <?php
                          foreach ($reports as $report) {
                              echo "'<a href="documents/$report.pdf"><img src="images/$report.jpg"><\/a>', ";
                          }
                      ?>
                     ];
    document.write(random_img[random_number]);
</script>
```

Edit: more explanation

This will create an array in javascript like so:

```
['<a href="documents/report1.pdf"><img src="images/report1.jpg"><\/a>',
 '<a href="documents/report2.pdf"><img src="images/report2.jpg"><\/a>',
];
```